# how to safely unwrapped header value

Tags: swift, collections, view

my app crashes as it finds nil when unwrapping the value "header" I tried using a guard let statement though it did not work , whats the best way to safely unwrapped this value?

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    self.headerOpen = true

    if self.headerOpen == true {

      let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! HomePageHeader

    header.currentUser = self.currentUser
    header.usersLocation = self.usersLocation
    header.delegate = self

    reloadInputViews()

    } else if headerOpen == false {


        print("header open is false")

        }




    return header!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if let ...` or `guard let ...` can help you. For example:

```
if let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as? HomePageHeader {
    print("header unwrapped")
}
```

or

```
guard let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as? HomePageHeader else { print("header not unwrapped") }
print("header unwrapped")
```

Comment: if let or guard don't seem to be working , with them i get the error; Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'HomePageHeader'

Comment: try to replace `!` to `?`.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using a guard let statement though it did not work

Because you are using `as!`, `!` means *forced unwrapping* of the value, which ignores the optional type and your app will crash if `UICollectionReusableView` does not conform to `HomePageHeader`.

You have to use `as?` to keep this safe, like so

```
guard let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as? HomePageHeader else {
    return UICollectionReusableView()
}

// do stuff with the header
header.currentUser = self.currentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**, you can `unwrap an optional` using one of the following ways:

**1.** Use **`!`** for forcefully unwrapping the `optional` value. To use `!`, you must be sure that the `optional` doesn't contain `nil`. Using `!` is a bit risky as unwrapping a `nil` value will result in a `runtime exception`.

```
let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! HomePageHeader
```

In the above code, you are forcefully unwrapping i.e.  `as! HomePageHeader`.

`collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath)` must be returning a `nil` which you are then unwrapping, as a result of which your app crashed.

**2.** Another option you can use to get an unwrapped value is using **`Optional Binding`**, i.e. **`if let`** statement.

> You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary constant
>   or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while statements
>   to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value
>   into a constant or variable, as part of a single action.

In your code, you can use it like:

```
if let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as? HomePageHeader
{
   header.currentUser = self.currentUser
   header.usersLocation = self.usersLocation
   header.delegate = self
}
```

`Optional Binding` only works on `optionals`. That's why, I have used `as? HomePageHeader` instead of `as! HomePageHeader`.

**3.** You can also use **`guard`** statement to handle `optional` values.

> A guard statement, like an if statement, executes statements depending
>   on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a guard statement to
>   require that a condition must be true in order for the code after the
>   guard statement to be executed. Unlike an if statement, a guard
>   statement always has an else clause—the code inside the else clause is
>   executed if the condition is not true.

In you code, you can use it like:

```
guard let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as? HomePageHeader else
{
   return
}
header.currentUser = self.currentUser
header.usersLocation = self.usersLocation
header.delegate = self
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.